Aubergines et pervenches
Utilise-t-on toujours le mot aubergine comme synonyme de pervenche (contractuelle auxiliaire de police patrouillant les parcmètres)? L'expression suivante est-elle encore comprise:

Cette aubergine m'a collé une prune.

pour signifier qu'on a pris une amende en raison d'un mauvais stationnement? Est-elle comprise partout dans la francophonie?

Moi je la compends mais je les ai connues. Tout dépend de l'âge des gens. Tu veux faire un sondage? Ou quel est le but de la question ?

Sondage, oui, pour recueillir des témoignages.

Dans les années 80, il y avait une série télé qui s'appelait Marie Pervenche

Les deux mots sont datés très précisément et très délimités géographiquement: tous deux font référence au trait le plus évident des contractuels, la couleur de leur uniforme. Cf. Lustucru pour les contractuels parisiens (inusité en province) et hirondelle, ancien sobriquet des policiers (non contractuels) patrouillant à bicyclette, en référence à leur pèlerine.

@FrançoisJurain Tu ne précises pas la géographie - penses-tu que c'était limité à Paris?

Je n'ai aucune information. Je suis sûr que c'était limité à la France et, sur la seule foi de mon petit doigt, je crois que c'était limité à Paris.

@FrançoisJurain Oui, je suis aussi persuadé que ces uniformes (aubergine puis pervenche) n'étaient utilisés qu'à Paris.

@FrançoisJurain Hirondelle était aussi et d'abord la marque des bicyclettes des policiers éponymes.

J'ai parlé de pervenche il y a un mois à ma fille ingénieure de 25 ans, elle ne savait pas ce que c'était. Alors aubergine...

Je ne l'ai plus entendu depuis des lustres. Il ne doit de toute façon plus y avoir de contractuelles, il me semble qu'à Paris, c'est une société privée qui met les contraventions (qu'on appelle plutôt FPS maintenant). Il y a aussi des voitures, genre Google Maps cars, qui scannent les plaques des voitures stationnées pour envoyer directement les amendes par courrier.
On appelle ces voitures des sulfateuses (à PV).

On n'arrête pas le progrès.

Une sulfateuse c'est aussi une mitraillette.

@Frank C'est bien pour ça qu'on les appelle comme ça. Elles mitraillent avec un bruit de tatouage infernal ;-)

Elles fondent à grands coups de FPS sur les stationnements abusifs!

Oups, aubergine commence à dater ! Si je me rappelle correctement, les tenues (violettes) qui avaient conduit à cette expression datent du début des années 1970. Les uniformes sont devenus ensuite très vite devenus bleus à partir de 1976 (ref.) et on a plutôt parlé de pervenches. Donc pour les moins de 50 ans, aubergine risque de n'évoquer aucun souvenir.
Pour pervenche l'uniforme a duré un peu plus longtemps. Il y a même eu une série télévisée Marie Pervenche de 1984 à 1991. Mais la fonction a disparu en 2018 (ref.).
